# Check which function arguments are missing/NULL

Tags: r, function, arguments, parameter-passing, default

I actually have two questions which both arose from a lack of understanding how arguments in an R function are handled.

1. I would like to get a vector indicating which arguments of a function `f(x,y)` are actually missing. Is there a more elegant way than the following solution:

   ```
   f <- function(x, y) {
     c(missing(x), missing(y))
   }
   ```
2. I also implemented a function which returns a logical variable indicating whether an argument is `NULL`:

   ```
   g <- function(x, y) {
     args_names <- as.list(environment())
     sapply(args_names, is.null)
   }
   ```

   While this functions works as intended, I am struggling to understand why `g(y=1)` does not return a `TRUE` for the first argument:

   ```
   > g(y=1)
       x     y 
   FALSE FALSE
   ```

Comment: `sapply(args_names, missing)` doesn't work because *"‘missing’ can only be used in the immediate body of the function that defines the argument, not in the body of a nested function or a ‘local’ call"*

Answer (score 2):

1. This seems a reasonable thing to do. Of course, if you had many more arguments you could think about `sapply`
2. For your second  question why not just return the args and see

   ```
   R> g <- function(x, y) {
   +    as.list(environment())
   + }
   R> args = g(10)
   R> str(args$y)
    symbol
   ```

   Of course the next question is what is a symbol, taken from [manual of all knowledge](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.pdf)

> Symbols refer to R objects. The name of any R object is usually a
>   symbol. Symbols can be created through the functions as.name and
>   quote. Symbols have mode "name", storage mode "symbol", and type
>   "symbol". They can be coerced to and from character strings using
>   as.character and as.name. They naturally appear as atoms of parsed
>   expressions, try e.g. as.list(quote(x + y)).

Answer (score 2):

Using `sapply`, you could go about it this way (and hope not too many kittens are killed:

```
f1 <- function(x,y) {
  sapply(names(formals()), function(arg) {
    eval.parent(call('missing', as.name(arg)), n=3)
  })
}
```

Comment: Is this a workaround to `missing()`'s doc: *"‘missing’ can only be used in the immediate body of the function that defines the argument, not in the body of a nested function or a ‘local’ call"*? Is it guaranteed to work? If yes, recommend you submit this to R doc on missing.